# How to convert conjunction inside disjunction into CNF?

Tags: logic, satisfiability

How do I convert something like $$\bigvee_{a\in A} \bigwedge_{i\in L} (x_{i,a} \wedge y_{i,a})$$
into CNF? The $x_{i,a}$ and $y_{i,a}$ are variables.

Comment: See **Conversion into CNF** in [CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) : "Every propositional formula can be converted into an equivalent formula that is in CNF".